# Modernizr and Boilerplate

Tags: html

I was doing a research about HTMl5 and This 2 comes out. One call Modernizr and the other one is Boilerplate. I want to know:

1.What is the different between Modernizr and Boilerplate?

2.Is it possible to run those together?

Comment: Why -1 for this? A novice can raise it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Modernizr is a feature detection library: it contains a range of tests you can use to determine whether a client supports various HTML5/CSS3 features. This allows you to use the standard features where available and fall back on hacks or shims when necessary.

Boilerplate is a collection of 'best practices': a CSS reset, some server config and so on, all with good sound defaults for HTML5 development.

You can and should use both in your HTML5 projects.